# Android - retrieve custom objects stored in a document in Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore as follows:

[image]

The collection 'events' holds documents that use unique event ID's as their names. In these documents are many 'EventComment' objects - each representing a comment made by a user.

To add the 'EventComment' object to the documents, I use the following:

```
EventComment mcomment = new EventComment();
mcomment.setComment("this is a comment");
Map<String, EventComment> eventMap = new HashMap<>();
eventMap.put(Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random())), mcomment);

    firestore.collection("events").document(event_id)
            .set(eventMap, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast.makeText(EventCommentsActivity.this, "ya bastud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

I create a `HashMap` of String and my object 'EventComment' and then set this in the document.

However, when I want to retrieve all the 'EventComment' objects contained in a given document, I cannot cast it to an EventComment object, i.e. I cannot do this:

```
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("events").document("vvG17ZfcLFVna8");
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        EventComment comment = documentSnapshot.toObject(EventComment.class);
    }
});
```

Also, trying to cast the documentSnapshot to a HashMap gives an 'unchecked cast' message and ultimately falls flat on its face. The idea is to use the comments to populate a RecyclerView.

I am thinking I may need to restructure the way I store the data?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are guessing right, you need to restructure the way you store the data. I'm saying that because the way you are storing the objects of type`EventComment` in your actual database is not correct. As you can see in the official documentation regarding [Quotas and Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), the maximum size for a document is `1MiB`. So if you continue to store the data like this, you'll reach the limit of `1MiB` in a very short time.

Remember, Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents. To solve this, I recommend you change the database structure like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- events (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- eventId (document)
   |     |     |
   |     |     --- //event details
   |     |
   |     --- eventId (document)
   |           |
   |           --- //event details
   |
   --- comments (collection)
         |
         --- eventId (document)
               |
               --- eventComments (collection)
                     |
                     --- eventCommentId (document)
                     |      |
                     |      --- //event comment details
                     |
                     --- eventCommentId (document)
                            |
                            --- //event comment details
```

As you can see, every obejct of type `EventComment` is added as a separate document within the `events` collection. In order to read the all the events objects, please use the following code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("events");
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        EventComment comment = documentSnapshot.toObject(EventComment.class);
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

If you want a list of `commnets` for a given eventId, please take a look again at the above database structure to see how it can be represented. And as you can you see, I have added a new collection named `comments` in which every new comment within a given eventId is also stored as a separate document. I came up with this structure to avoid nested maps.

If you are interested, you can take a look at one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** in which I have explained step by step, how to structure the database needed for the app.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response. This does make more sense, but if I want a list of ‘commnets’ for a given eventID, how would this be best represented? Would my model in-code need a list defined or could I have a sub collection of comments? The EventComment model is meant to represent 1 comment made by 1 user

Comment: You're welcome @Zach To achieve what you want, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Alex, I watched your tutorial and it was very useful - thank you! It did in fact work and I am able to get the collection and then map it to an ArrayList in code. I'm now watching your Firebase RecyclerView tutorial :)

Comment: Got it populating in a RecyclerView, thanks to your tutorial and how-to Stackoverflow Q&A :)