# Retrieve map data from document and convert the value type

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I stored some data in cloud firestore like this : collection->document->map<String, User) look at screenshot.
[image]
I want to retrieve the data stored in that map what i do :

```
for(DocumetnSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots){
  Map<String, Object> myMap = doc.getData()}
```

The problem is that i want to retrieve the value of the map as User type but with this method i retrieve it as Object type and i cant cast it what is the solution.

**EDIT**

My User class:

```
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String user_id;
    private String username;
    private String location;
    private String status;
    private String priceUnit;

    public User(String email, String user_id, String username, String location, String status, String price) {
        this.email = email;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.username = username;
        this.location = location;
        this.status = status;
        this.priceUnit = price;
    }

    public User() { }

    public String getPriceUnit() {
        return priceUnit;
    }

    public void setPriceUnit(String priceUnit) {
        this.priceUnit = priceUnit;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

My code to save data is:

```
                rentMeRequestListRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                            if (doc.getId().equals(user.getUser_id())){
                                rentMeRequestListRef.document(user.getUser_id()).get()
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                        Map<String, Object> mapGet = new HashMap<>();
                                        mapGet = documentSnapshot.getData();
                                        mapGet.put(renterUser.getUser_id(), renterUser);
                                        rentMeRequestListRef.document(user.getUser_id()).set(mapGet);
                                    }
                                });
                            }else{
                                rentMeRequestListRef.document(user.getUser_id()).get()
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                        if (!documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                            rentMeRequestListRef.document(user.getUser_id()).set(rentMeMap);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If not, show us the entire code that you're using to read the data from Firestore and how your User class looks like.

Comment: No i didnt solved yet i will edit and post the code you asked me for

Comment: Ok, leave a message when you're done editing.

Comment: @AlexMamo it's ok

Comment: Can you also show us, how the `rentMeRequestListRef` object is defined?

Comment: It's like in the screenshot.  CollectionReference rentMeRequestListRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("RentMe Request");

Comment: Why are you using the `Xpfr...Dom1` as the key of the Map?

Comment: As key of the map im putting the user id, and the id is generated automatically

Comment: i'll explain what am doing it's a renting app in first we have the doc (the renter) and the document is named by the user id (renter) then in that document there are the list of object he want to rent (in this exemple other users(screenshot)) i used map to classifie by user id and the value is data about the object

Comment: Are you allowed to change the database schema?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for a better schema ?

Comment: I just saw this topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621231/android-retrieve-custom-objects-stored-in-a-document-in-cloud-firestore) he have same problem as me and you already answered him by restructuring the way he store the data i think i will try the same think

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.